# Convert Function to Static

Tags: php, oop, pdo

I want to convert following function to static.This function in class. It is working properly.

```
class LoginDBHandler extends DBConnection
    {
        private $loginObj;
        private $table="user_login";
        private $statement;

        public function __construct()
        {
            parent::__construct();
            $this->loginObj=new userLogin();
        }

        //Other Non-static Methods

        public function authenticate($username,$password)
        {
                $password=password_hash($password,PASSWORD_BCRYPT,Config::$password_options);
                $this->statement=$this->pdo->prepare("select * from $this->table where username=:username and password=:password and isActive=1");
                $this->statement->bindParam(":username",$username);
                $this->statement->bindParam(":password",$password);
                $this->statement->execute();
                $this->statement->fetchAll();
                if($this->statement->rowCount()==1)
                {
                    return true;
                }
                else
                {
                    return false;
                }
        }
}
```

I tried it in follwing way.

```
class LoginDBHandler extends DBConnection
    {
        private $loginObj;
        private $table="user_login";
        private $statement;

        public function __construct()
        {
            parent::__construct();
            $this->loginObj=new userLogin();
        }

        //Other Non-static Methods

        public static function authenticate($username,$password)
        {
                $password=password_hash($password,PASSWORD_BCRYPT,Config::$password_options);
                $this->statement=self::$pdo->prepare("select * from $this->table where username=:username and password=:password and isActive=1");
                $this->statement->bindParam(":username",$username);
                $this->statement->bindParam(":password",$password);
                $this->statement->execute();
                $this->statement->fetchAll();
                if($this->statement->rowCount()==1)
                {
                    return true;
                }
                else
                {
                    return false;
                }
        }
}
```

But PDO is not accessible. I have other non-function which also use PDO.How should i access it?

**DBConnection**

```
<?php

    class DBConnection
    {
        protected $pdo;

        public function __construct()
        {
            $this->pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost; dbname=db_inventory;","root","");
            $this->pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
            $this->pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
            $this->pdo->exec("set names utf8"); 
        }

    }

?>
```

Is it good to use static methods for authentication and for other database operation non static methods? Is it good to extend class or should i use getmethod for pdo?

Comment: You cannot use any object properties in a static method. That is because there is no object. So you cannot use `$this`. You _can_ use shared or static properties though. But remember that without object no constructor is executed. So basically a static method cannot really depend on anything class internal, except constants.

Answer (score 1):

You can not use $this in static functions, You can use in static method static or self. Please check documentation for more.